# Unable to use proper Generic Repository Structure C# MVC With Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have a Interface named IRepository and class named Repository to implement Repository pattern in C# MVC as

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    {
        void Insert(TEntity entity);
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
    }

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
    {
        DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
        TestDBEntities dataContext;

        public Repository(TestDBEntities dataContext)
        {
            this.dataContext = dataContext;
            this.DbSet = dataContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(predicate);
        }

    }
```

and here is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private IRepository<Tbl_EmpDetails> _EmpDetails;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _EmpDetails = new Repository<Tbl_EmpDetails>(new TestDBEntities());
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Tbl_EmpDetails empDetials)
    {
        _EmpDetails.Insert(empDetials);
        return Redirect("/");
    }

}
```

As per my idea in controller i should not have to use "new TestDBEntities()" because instance of EDMX will be create again and again when Insert,Update,Delete or any another function of controller will call and there will be no use of Repository. (TestDBEntity is object of my EDMX).

```
_EmpDetails = new Repository<Tbl_EmpDetails>(new TestDBEntities());
```

Tbl_EmpDetails is an table under EDMX.

Please suggest me what is the perfect way to implement repository structure according to my code and also if you have any other Suggestion to improve my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's very helpful to take a look at  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. it's describe change the use of repository instead of directly context step by step.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i structure my project.

```
Project.Web
    -> Controllers

Project.Domain
    -> Contracts
    -> Services

Project.Data
    -> Contracts
    -> Repositories
```

---

So in my controller, only the service was exposed (so all the implementations are encapsulated). I used `ninject` to handle this dependencies.

```
public SomeController(IService service)
{
}
```

**INSIDE MY DOMAIN PROJECT**

An interface and a class that derived that interface was implemented. So basically, this only calls the repository project and other business logic should reside here.

**The interface**

```
public interface IService
    {
        IEnumerable<SomeClass> FindAll();
    }
```

**The implementation**

```
public class Service : IService
    {
        private ISomeRepository _someRepository; // Exposed instance of my repo

        public IEnumerable<SomeClass> FindAll()
        {
            return _someRepository.FindAll();
        }
    }
```

**INSIDE MY DATA PROJECT**

I also have two implementations one for the interface and another one for the class which implementing this interface.

**The interface**

```
public interface ISomeRepository
    {        
        IEnumerable<Some> FindAll();
    }
```

**The implementation**

```
 public class SomeRepository : BaseRepository, ISomeRepository
    {
        public R(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            : base(unitOfWork)
        { 

        }

        public IEnumerable<SomeClass> FindAll() 
        {
            return this.GetDbSet<SomeClass>();
        }
    }
```

If you wonder what is the use of `BaseRepository` and `UnitOfWork`, this will holds the context of our model (EDMX).

**Base Repository**

```
 public class BaseRepository
        {
            protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

            protected MyEntities Context
            {
                get { return (MyEntities)this.UnitOfWork.Database; }
            }

            public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            {
                if (unitOfWork == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");
                this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            }

            protected virtual DbSet<TEntity> GetDbSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
            {
                return this.Context.Set<TEntity>();
            }

            protected virtual void SetEntityState(object entity, EntityState entityState)
            {
                this.Context.Entry(entity).State = entityState;
            }
        }
```

**Unit Of Work**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        public DbContext Database { get; private set; }

        public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            Database = dbContext;
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            Database.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose() 
        {
            Database.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The IUnitOfWork interface

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        DbContext Database { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Saves changes to all objects that have changed within the unit of work.
        /// </summary>
        void SaveChanges();
    }
```

So for this, we cater the issue of separation of concerns and each project serves it's true purpose

Comment: Thanks Desperado, But i just want to confirm that is my implementations are fine or what i have to need to improve my code... According to you, Am i doing right implementations?? Especially In controller's constructor by adding "new TestDBEntities()".

Comment: @AmandeepSingh that is not right, controller should not directly modify the context because if there are any business logics later on, the controller will be crowded and we don't like that

Comment: OK @Desperado,Thanks again.  Can you please modify my code into best structure as simplest as possible???? as I am new with this concept.

Comment: I'm just implementing it and let you know. Thanks